# Странный эффект подсветки сообщения в чате

Tags: дефект, дизайн, чат

Если в чате открыть родительское сообщение, то будет скролл к нему и жёлтая подсветка.
Но так же будет уменьшения тела сообщения, что мешает взаимодействовать с звёздами и ответом на это сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это результат такого CSS:

```
.message.highlight {
    margin-right: 48px
}
```

Какой в этом смысл, если он есть и, если это баг, не стоило бы его пофиксить?

Comment: да, странноватое свойство